# GeoPandas: How to plot hexagon geometry?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe with hexagon geometry and a label and I am having trouble figuring out how to:

1. plot the hexagons with my own color scheme
2. show the legend

a snippet of the data looks like:

```
    geometry    pred_labels color
0   POLYGON ((63.06967 29.61571, 63.07798 29.60487...   1   0.000000
1   POLYGON ((63.18163 29.99343, 63.18998 29.98255...   3   0.666667
2   POLYGON ((62.99624 29.69126, 63.00458 29.68042...   1   0.000000
3   POLYGON ((63.32191 29.58779, 63.33018 29.57693...   1   0.000000
4   POLYGON ((63.64046 29.59359, 63.64869 29.58271...   1   0.000000

10509 rows × 3 columns
```

when I plot:

```
df_january.plot(cmap='Purples', legend=True);
```

[image: pic]

I get something that appears right, but if I specify column to pred_labels or color, I will get very wonky and messed up plots. For instance:

```
df_january.plot(column='pred_labels', cmap='Purples', legend=True);
```

[image]

Zoomed in more:

[image]

Comment: Hexagonal geometry? There is nothing hexagonal in either image. 
Also are you sure you're using geopandas: it normally renders the geometry field on the far right end of the table, rather than first.

Comment: Re-orientating the dataframe so the geometry column is last seemed to help!

Comment: With geopandas, it is worth making sure to use the `set_geometry` method to ensure it know which field holds the geometry. Otherwise it looks like it assumes it is in the last column.

Answer (score 0):

Following J.Warren, placing the geometry column at the end of the df improved plotting.

Comment: Can you explain (code-wise) what have you done to fix the issue? The order of columns should have no effect on plotting in geopandas.

Comment: ```df_january = df[(df.time_index == 1)].reset_index(drop=True)
df_january = df_january[['pred_labels', 'geometry']]```  The order did seem to matter.